# Automatic login in website using login and password list

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to do something but I have no idea where to start, the idea is as follows:

I have a website where I'm testing the logins registered, I basically have to put login and password starting from a list that I get and check if the registration is or is not working, there are days that the list I get is huge and I wanted to automate it, no matter which way (js, vbs, c #) only automate...

I will try to explain better, for to be no doubt

I have a list of logins and passwords I want to automate, where I put the logins and passwords, and the "program" will testing one by one and separating what worked and what did not.

I'm not asking for someone give me all set, I just want to know where to start, what better way, so I can do it myself.

if anyone can help me I will be grateful, I hope I have explained the best way for you to understand.

sorry for my Inglês, I am writing this before going to work and I'm already late haha and Inglês is not my native language